# Slow multiplication in a modulo

Tags: javascript, mathematics

I am willing to get a linear output of a product in a ring Z/nZ

For that I have successfully implemented a code that does a Product in a modulo
However, it is not optimized to output the steps smoothly:

```js
/* Product of n1 x n2 x n3 modulo M */

var numbers=[n1,n2,n3];
var modulo= M;

var AProd=1;
var BProd=numbers[0];

var accu=0;

var nProd=true;
var iProd=0;
var kProd=0;

var tritemp = 0;

    
function ProductModulo() {

 if (AProd == 1 || iProd == 0) {
     nProd = false;
 }

 if (nProd && tritemp == 0) {
     if (accu > 1) {
         tritemp = accu;
     } else {
         tritemp = AProd;
     }
 }

 if (nProd && 10 * tritemp <= accu) {
     accu = 10 * tritemp;
     nProd = false;
     tritemp = 0;

 }

 if (nProd) {
     accu += tritemp; //arbitrary
 }


 if (AProd == 1) {
     kProd = BProd.toString().length;
 } else if (!nProd) {

     if (tritemp == 0) {
         tritemp = accu + Number(AProd.toString()[iProd]) * Number(BProd.toString()[kProd]) * Math.pow(10, BProd.toString().length - 1 - kProd);

     }

     accu += 50; //arbitrary

     if (accu >= tritemp) {
         accu = tritemp;
         tritemp = 0;
         kProd++;
     }
 }

 if (kProd == BProd.toString().length) {

     accu = accu % modulo;

     iProd++;
     kProd = 0;
     nProd = true;
     tritemp = 0;

 }

 if (iProd == AProd.toString().length) {

     if (AProd == 1) {
         AProd = BProd;
     } else {
         AProd = accu;
     }

     numbers.splice(0, 1);
     iProd = 0;

     if (numbers.length > 0) {
         BProd = numbers[0];
         accu = 0;
     }
 }

 if (numbers.length == 0) {
     //display result accu, calculation is done
     console.log("Final Result: " + accu);

 } else {
     // (could display accu)
     ProductModulo();
 }

}
```

**EDIT** [Here is a test](http://s584381281.onlinehome.fr/test/) page to see it in action

The code works [as follow](http://www.nugae.com/encryption/fap4.htm):

- step 1: We take the current number in accumulator and multiply by 10
- step 2: We take the first digit (of AProd) and multiply by Bprod
- step 3: we add result of step 2 to result of step 1 and modulo M of it
- step 4: Same as Step 1, 2 and 3 with the next digit of AProd

...
When all Aprods digits have been done we do the same between the result and n3

So, this code works but the problem is I would like a more linear way of visualizing the whole process. For instance I already show all the steps of additions instead of outputing the result directly.

Is there a smooth way, of increasing the accu, and is it possible to work on n1 and n2 and n3 at the same time instead of doing, (n1*n2) and then *n3?

Note: I am only interested with numbers positive and co-prime with the modulo

Comment: I recommend you put your code through a cleaner or tidy service, that's very hard to read and messy to look at

Comment: I did, and added a test page where we can see it in action

Comment: @lopata your test link does not work